# How to download sitecore CMS for personal/learning purpose?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore

I have been trying to download a copy of sitecore CMS for learning purposes. But when I goto their site it asks me for which client / organization I'm going to build this? So Is there anyway I could download a trail copy of CMS for my own use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can't download Sitecore because it's not free or Sitecore doesn't provide any trial version. To perform this you should have Sitecore certification or certified member credentials.

Please contact any near person who can provide you Sitecore.

Comment: Sitecore has always been greedy for money, drop it and go for EPiServer

Answer (score 0):

In general, sitecore is not free and has more or less discontinued their "xpress" version of the software.  You may be able to talk to the sales team, but unfortunately, it's not likely going to get you any where (from my own experience anyway).  If you're company has a sitecore license, you should look into using that.